# Unable to create new Angular app using Angular CLI version 9.1.3 (and Node version 12.16.2)

Tags: angular

The error is:

```
Installing packages...
... # NPM warnings omitted from the log
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...8.11","gulp-clang-for'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    C:\Users\prane\AppData\Roaming\NPM-cache\_logs\2020-04-25T13_54_27_983Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: it says in the error message TSLint has been deprecated. you should us ESLint

Comment: This problem happened after you installed new version of angular or npm? Tried cleaning the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is related to npm, just try to clear the npm cache by using the following command and try again it will work.

```
npm cache clean --force
```